# Run exe from stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the next situation: I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which inserts data into a table called `Orders`. Then there are users connected via remote desktop to the server machine that runs the SQL Server. What I want to do is to notify all the connected users that a new row in the table `Orders` has been inserted.

The code of stored procedure:

```
declare @cmd varchar(200);
set @cmd = 'start C:\DB\program.exe';
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd , no_output;
```

The code in the vb program:

```
Module Module1
    Private WithEvents notify As New NotifyIcon()
    Sub Main()
        notify.Text = "Info and time " & DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        notify.Icon = New Icon(SystemIcons.Application, 40, 40)
        notify.Visible = True
        notify.ShowBalloonTip(10000, "Title", "Some text  " & DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), ToolTipIcon.Info)
    End Sub
End Module
```

If you run the exe, the notification shows.

The procedure is executed and inserts the record, but the notification never shows up.

Which alternatives do I have?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If your DBA allows executing xp_cmdshell, then it might be time to look for another!! :)  Don't do it like that. Find another way.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i'm just looking for options. I'm thinking in various approaches and this is not the definitive one.

Comment: Two words, Service Broker...

Comment: Why can't you run the stored procedure from the vb program and use that to notify the users when the procedure has successfully executed?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I decided to use other alternative with windows tasks and stuff.